# Way to oblige AspectJ to throw a runtime error if it can't find/put to run the given aspect files?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to run a complex application with complex classpaths and JVM options with some load-time aspects woven in. At the moment it doesn't seem to be doing anything, but I can't know for sure if it is in some way related to a bug in my code or in the aspect not being loaded at all. Is there any special switch that will alert me if a given aspect is not being loaded (and possible, the issue at hand)?

I've looked up the [aj command line script](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/aj-ref.html), but it doesn't look particularly useful :(

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I forgot to mention that the option you want is `-showWeaveInfo` rather than (or in addition to) `-verbose`. While the latter shows if an aspect has been registered at all, the former shows where it is woven into your classes.

---

In chapter 5 of the The [AspectJ Development Environment Guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/index.html) you find information about

- [configuring Load-time Weaving with aop.xml files](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#configuring-load-time-weaving-with-aopxml-files) including samples for weaver options `verbose` and `dump within`,
- a short reference of [weaver options](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#weaver-options).

The former writes information about processed LTW aspects on `System.err`, the latter dumps all classes in specified packages to a specific directory where you can then inspect them and see if they have been woven as desired.